# Microsoft Identity Platform V2 not working with personal accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid, microsoft-identity-platform

I have setup a new app-registration on Azure, to perform OpenId authentication of my application. I have allowed personal accounts to connect to my application:

[image: app setup]

I can log into my application using my Azure Work account.

However, when I use a live account, I get the following error (AADSTS50020):

[image: error]

> Do I really need to add all users who want to authenticate to the tenant? What if I have a public application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really need to add all users who want to authenticate to the
>   tenant? What if I have a public application?

No, you have used Microsoft Identity Platform V2 and allowed personal accounts to connect. The personal account should be able to login in without being added as a guest.

1.Make sure you are using 'common' as the value of TenantId.

2.Make sure you are using v2.0 endpoint.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-3-AnyOrgOrPersonal) for your reference.

Comment: This was indeed my problem! I was using the authentication endpoint provided by the .well-known configuration. That was a v1 endpoint.